# Appropriate Method for Generating Confidence Intervals for Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I am attempting to generate confidence intervals for a neural network, according to the article [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-bootstrap-confidence-intervals-machine-learning-results-python/), one would bootstrap from the training set to generate new models several times, and then apply the model to the validation set *n* number of times to generate the relevant statistics.

Is there another way to generate confidence intervals that doesn't require retraining the network? Retraining the network is very computationally intense and requires a great deal of time-- so I would like to avoid it if at all possible.

Thanks so much!

Comment: are you looking specifically for confidence intervals, or would you be interested also in credible intervals?

Comment: If credible intervals are an important consideration with neural nets then I would be interested in hearing about them as they pertain to this matter.

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked threads. Please 
read them. If they aren't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.